# Dumper is changing the order of output . Can't we print the output in the same order as how the bytes are parsed during decoding the bytes?

Tags: perl

I am decoding a cbor encoded hex string using Cbor::XS module. After decoding I am printing the decoded data using dumper. But the order of output is not same as how the string is parsed. Is there any way to maintain the order?

I am attaching the code that I used

```
use CBOR::XS;
     my $hex_data =    "84AA1A300000031901001A10000002031A1000000A011A700001F7011A600003F11B0000023D19D43C001A600003F0001A800003EE41011A900003EF51300F310D300B0603550403130446616B651A600002BD1B00000189DB1BABD91A2000000142020340A040";
    my $data = pack "H*", $hex_data;
    my $decoded_data = CBOR::XS::decode_cbor($data);

    use Data::Dumper;
    local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
    print Dumper($decoded_data);
```

Expected output

[{805306371: 256, 268435458: 3, 268435466: 1, 1879048695: 1, 1610613745: 2461449600000, 1610613744: 0, 2147484654: "1", 2415920111: "0\0171\r0\13\6\3U\4\3\23\4Fake", 1610613437: 1691598171097, 536870913: '0203'}, '', {}, '']

Actual Output

```
  $VAR1 = [
          {
            "1610613437" => '1691598171097',
            "1879048695" => 1,
            "536870913" => "\2\3",
            "1610613744" => 0,
        "805306371" => 256,
        "2415920111" => "0\0171\r0\13\6\3U\4\3\23\4Fake",
        "268435466" => 1,
        "1610613745" => '2461449600000',
        "2147484654" => "\1",
        "268435458" => 3
      },
      "",
      {},
      ""
    ];
```

So you can see the order is not maintained in the actual output. Please help resolve this.

Comment: The hash keys in Perl are not keeping the order of insertion. If you run the program several times, you will see that the order is changing. This is the correct behaviour.

Comment: See https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks for details on why hash order is randomized.

Comment: If you want to retain the original order of the data, you must use an array. But in this case, the module stores the data, so you must look to that module's documentation for help.  Data::Dumper has options for sorting output, but it does not know the original order.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to maintain order, you shouldn't serialize your data as a hash, which, by design, will not maintain it and is the wrong data structure for your use case.
Serialize it as an Array and if you need to you can easily convert it into a Hash.

```
my @persisted_log = ({event1 => 'some data'}, {event2 => { kind => 'blue' }}, ...);

my %jumbled = map { $_->%* } @persisted_log;

# but now you can
if (my $value = $jumbled{event1}) 
{ 
     do_something_smart_with($value) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The elements of Perl hashes are not ordered. Same goes for JSON objects, Python dictionaries, etc. This is pretty common. One shouldn't use a CBOR map for ordered data.